# Room can't retrieve the following columns

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

This is the entity but I don't see any problem with this page.
I can get the word but not the other 4 columns.
    @Entity(tableName = "words")
public class Model {

```
@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
private int id;
@ColumnInfo(name = "en_word")
private String en_word;
@ColumnInfo(name = "en_definition")
private String en_definition;
@ColumnInfo(name = "example")
private String example;
@ColumnInfo(name = "synonyms")
private String synonyms;
@ColumnInfo(name = "antonyms")
private String antonyms;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEn_word() {
    return en_word;
}

public void setEn_word(String en_word) {
    this.en_word = en_word;
}

public String getEn_definition() {
    return en_definition;
}

public void setEn_definition(String en_definition) {
    this.en_definition = en_definition;
}

public String getExample() {
    return example;
}

public void setExample(String example) {
    this.example = example;
}

public String getSynonyms() {
    return synonyms;
}

public void setSynonyms(String synonyms) {
    this.synonyms = synonyms;
}

public String getAntonyms() {
    return antonyms;
}

public void setAntonyms(String antonyms) {
    this.antonyms = antonyms;
}
```

}

This is the query from DAO

```
@Query("SELECT en_definition, example,synonyms,antonyms FROM words WHERE UPPER(:text)")
Cursor getMeaning(String text);
```

and this from the activity

```
 Cursor c = application.getmDatabase().wordsDao().getMeaning(enWord);
    Log.d(TAG, enWord);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

        enDefinition= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("en_definition"));
        example=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("example"));
        synonyms=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("synonyms"));
        antonyms=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("antonyms"));

        Log.d(TAG, enDefinition);  //no output

    }
```

I can log the enWord but can't reach the 4 columns within.It's working fine in databasehelper class but no output with room.

Comment: Please post your Entity

Comment: You SQL WHERE clause looks wrong.  There should be a condition.

Comment: I edited with the entity.

Answer (score 2):

Please edit your query to:

```
@Query("SELECT en_definition, example, synonyms, antonyms FROM words WHERE en_word = UPPER(:text)")
Cursor getMeaning(String text);
```